# Windows 7 Home premium Service pack 1

Tags: wireless-networking

I am running Win7 AP1 Having a bizarr WLAN problem. I can connect 
to my WLAN properly. However, after a while the connection shuts down and I
Have to run the network trouble shooter to bring it back. Diagnostic always sys
The wireless capability is shut down. After diag, is asks if I want to turn on
wireless capability though I haven't disabled it. Comes back but it annoying.
Also after reboot have to run diags to get it running. Anyone seen this before?
Thanks.

Comment: Lots of WIFI stuff is very buggy - particularly older equipment.  Have you tried updating your WLAN driver ?

Comment: Yes. Did that but still acts flaky. This laptop is kind of old. If i cant get it working in a few days , looks I may need to buy A new one. Stuff happens.